# HTTP and HTTPS port

Tags: glassfish-3

I have created a J2EE application that runs on GlassFish, HTTPS enabled. When the user typed http: //www.mydomain.com:8080/app, it will be redirected to https: //www.mydomain.com:8181/app/login.

However, when I see in some of the websites, it can actually redirected to something like https: //www.mydomain.com/app/login (without the HTTPS port 8181). Does this means that the server is running both HTTP and HTTPS on port 80?

How to configure this on GlassFish 3.1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Non-root user should not use ports below 1024.
It is better to do port forwarding from 80 to 8080 and 443 (https default) to 8181.

Execute this as root:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8181
```

Need to make this permanent:

```
iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

and call during startup, *vi /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload*

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

Comment: Don't forget to make `iptablesload` executable with `chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload`!

Comment: your answer has saved me a lot of trouble trying to front glassfish with apache. thank you so much.

Comment: One question though. I get permission denied when trying to make the change permanent even when running the commands as root. How can I do this. Running Ubuntu server 16.04. I can also see that there is no iptables.rules in the location specified. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can also configure it in the admin web gui under:
`Configuration -> Server Config -> Network Config -> Network Listeners`

Answer (score 3):

Just to give out more details on alexblum's answer, when you login into the Glassfish Admin panel, go to `Configurations -> server-config -> Network Listeners in Network Config`.

1. Then click on New to add a new listener.
2. On the new listener page, just select **80** as your port and put **0.0.0.0** as your IP.
3. Select **tcp** as your Transport and use **http-thread-pool** as your Thread Pool
4. Save and **Restart** your Glassfish instance.

Thats what worked for me anyways.

Comment: this didn't work. After making these changes, domain isn't started.

Comment: Try starting the domain with root account. It requires privilege for port 80.

Answer (score 2):

The default port for HTTP is 80. When you access a URL: http://www.example.com/ you are connecting to `www.example.com:80`.

The default port for HTTPS is 443. When you access a URL: https://www.example.com/ you are connecting to `www.example.com:443`.

(See [List of port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers))

(See [configuration of GlassFish to use other ports](http://blogs.oracle.com/openroad/entry/changing_default_glassfish_port_numbers))